# getShardDistribution() using pymongo driver

Tags: python, mongodb, python-2.7, sharding

I was trying to figure out if it is possible to get the mongo shell equivalent of db.collection.getShardDistribution() in python (using pymongo driver)?

Comment: [`db.collection.getShardDistribution()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.getShardDistribution/) is actually a "script" and not part any driver "per se". If you want to know what these shell "helpers" are doing, simply type in `db.<mycollectionName>.getShardDistribution` being the method without the brackets `()`. This actually shows you the "scripted function" which is implemented in the shell. The actual function script uses driver methods to return the results. So you can simply look at that and reproduce for your driver code.

Comment: In short, it's a bunch of queries on the `"config"` database which is present on sharded clusters. So it's not like this is a database command or any method that a driver needs to implement. Just a "helper".

Comment: great, this helps, thank you Neil.